# Reading from a CSV file to ping websites

Tags: c#, csv, ping

Yes, this is from a homework assignment, but even my professor is baffled as to why it's not working, so I came here. The idea is to read from one CSV file, ping all the URLs in there, and put the resulting data into a second CSV file. The problem is that the code keeps looping back to the first URL in the CSV file, and will starting returning an error message after it passes that first URL.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Timers;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;


namespace Project04
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string choice;
        //menu
        do
        {

            Console.WriteLine("Select an option:");
            Console.WriteLine("A) Start Ping");
            Console.WriteLine("B) Stop Ping");
            Console.WriteLine("C) Exit");
            choice = Console.ReadLine();

            switch (choice)
            {
                case "A":
                    RunPing();
                    break;

                case "B":
                    //stop method
                    //needed?
                    break;

                default:
                    break;

            }
            Console.Clear();


        } while (choice != "C");

    }
    public static void RunPing()
    {
        //timer
        System.Timers.Timer aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
        aTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);
        aTimer.Interval = 5000;
        aTimer.Enabled = true;

        Console.WriteLine("Press 'B' to stop.");
        while (Console.Read() != 'B');

    }
    private static void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        //csv reader
        using (TextFieldParser parser = new TextFieldParser("Project04_URLs.csv"))
        {
            parser.TextFieldType = FieldType.Delimited;
            parser.SetDelimiters(",");
            while (!parser.EndOfData)
            {

                string[] fields = parser.ReadFields();
                foreach (string URL in fields)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        //ping
                        Ping myPing = new Ping();
                        PingReply reply = myPing.Send(URL, 5000);
                        if (reply != null)
                        {
                            //write ping to other csv
                            StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("Ping_Data.csv");
                            writer.WriteLine("Status :  " + reply.Status + " \n Time : " + reply.RoundtripTime.ToString() + " \n Address : " + reply.Address);
                        }
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("ERROR: You have Some TIMEOUT issue");
                    }
                    Console.ReadKey();
                    Console.Clear();
                }

            }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

The initial CSV file (Project04_URLs) contains these URLs.

```
na02.mypinpointe.com
na03.mypinpointe.com
na04.mypinpointe.com
na05.mypinpointe.com
na06.mypinpointe.com
na07.mypinpointe.com
na08.mypinpointe.com

na09.mypinpointe.com
na10.mypinpointe.com
na11.mypinpointe.com
```

The second CSV file (Ping_Data) is empty.

Thanks for any help that you can give.

Comment: you should break your code up into smaller testable functions. that would be a good place to start.

Comment: Why data in Project04_URLs csv file is comma separated?

Comment: what is the output? what is the error?

Answer (score 0):

Some observations with your code:

1. Your Timer fires every 5 seconds - which means every 5 sec your code tries to ping every URL from the CSV file.
2. You have a Console.ReadKey() near the end of For loop - which will stop the for execution in every iteration and wait for user input.
3. Within the for loop - you have an undisposed StreamWriter opening and writing to same file (filename is hardcode) all the time - which means (along with #1) you may have file access issue - where more than one thread (timer fire) is operating on same disk file. Also input csv file is being opened multiple times too.

Advice:

1. Use TextFieldParser - in a short scope. Maybe just extract the urls in a string array and dispose the TextFieldParser
2. Think over do you really need the Console.ReadKey() after every url is pinged in the for loop. If you go away from the computer for 20 mins you have many threads waiting for Console input. Use thread sync techniques (ex: ManualResetEvent) to design timer thread exit after B is pressed on console. Or You can also use a **"cheap hack"** bool variable being set from MAIN() method and check the bool variable in the Timer fire method every time and return if set.
3. Create a dynamic name for the output csv file where you are writing he Ping result. Something like

   var wrtr = new StreamWriter (string.Format("Ping_Data_{0}_{1}.csv", URL, DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyyy-HHmmss")));

---

This is how my code is (Still don't know why you need a Timer). Note that bool _Terminate is a disgraceful exit flag - meaning that every timer thread will exit as soon as possible. Another strategy would be to remove the bool flag itself (i.e. only disable the timer). In that case each thread will exit as soon as it completes all it's  workload (i.e. all URL's in the CSV are pinged).

```
namespace Project04
{
    class Program
    {
        static bool _Terminate = false;
        static Timer aTimer = new Timer();

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            aTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);
            aTimer.Interval = 5000;

            string choice;
            //menu
            do
            {

                Console.WriteLine("Select an option:");
                Console.WriteLine("A) Start Ping");
                Console.WriteLine("B) Stop Ping");
                Console.WriteLine("C) Exit");
                choice = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper();

                switch (choice)
                {
                    case "A":
                        _Terminate = false;
                        RunPing();
                        break;

                    case "B":
                        _Terminate = true;
                        break;

                    default:
                        break;

                }
                Console.Clear();


            } while (choice != "C");

        }
        public static void RunPing()
        {            
            aTimer.Enabled = true;
        }

        private static void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            string[] fields = null;
            //csv reader
            using (TextFieldParser parser = new TextFieldParser("Project04_URLs.csv"))
            {
                parser.TextFieldType = FieldType.Delimited;
                parser.SetDelimiters(",");
                fields = parser.ReadFields();
            }

            foreach (string URL in fields)
            {
                if (_Terminate)
                {
                    aTimer.Enabled = false;
                    return;
                }
                try
                {
                    //ping
                    Ping myPing = new Ping();
                    PingReply reply = myPing.Send(URL, 5000);
                    if (reply != null)
                    {
                        //write ping to other csv
                        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(string.Format("Ping_Data-{0}-{1}.csv", URL, DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyyy-HHmmss"))))
                        {
                            writer.WriteLine("Status :  " + reply.Status + " \n Time : " + reply.RoundtripTime.ToString() + " \n Address : " + reply.Address);
                            // Redundant
                            writer.Flush();
                            writer.Close();
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("ERROR: You have Some TIMEOUT issue");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I haven't added any resource sharing synchronization techniques here (lock etc) assuming this is a School assignment and Kid may have not reached that Chapter yet.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I really appreciate it. Not mentioning the purpose of the timer was my bad. It's there to ping the URLs every 5 seconds, the assignment needs to be turned in with 1 hour of data. Since it's 1:30 am here I'll test out your advice when I wake up.